# What does number~ output?

Tags: max-msp-jitter

I just started learning `msp`, I wanted to see what does the cycle~ output, so I patch it to the number~ and print out all those momentary values. they are all float numbers jumping between -1 and 1. The help doc says it is signal value, but what signal value exactly? like the amplitude?

The values of the number~ outputs:

[image: the values of the number~ outputs]

Answer (score 1):

A signal consists of 44100 values per second, and number~ outputs only 10 of these values per second.

So the values you are seeing are snapshots of the output of cycle~, which produces a sine wave, but a very fast one, 301 periods per second in your example. So the values you see will not seem to form a pattern.

More info can be found [in the docs](https://docs.cycling74.com/max8/tutorials/03_msphowmspworks).

Tip: if you change the frequency of cycle~ in your example to say 1 instead of 301, you will notice the sine pattern in the printed output.

Comment: thanks! it's easier and clearer when I set a low frequency for cycle~